# Массив строк в си

Tags: c

Подскажите пожалуйста есть ли способ создать в си динамически расширяемый массив строк. Чтобы пользователь вводил предложение и оно по словам было занесено в массив. Перепробовал много, но так ничего не нашел((( Большое спасибо за любые советы.

Comment: Да, можно - `realloc`.

Comment: но ведь заранее не известен размер массива. И нужно с помощью getchar() посимвольно получать данные?Например, чтобы изначально размер был равен 0 изначально?

Comment: Выделять память блоками. Если входных данных больше, чем выделено, расширять на новый блок.

Comment: Не понятно, как получить сами слова с помощью gets()  или scanf, при этом ставя ограничение '\t'? Большое спасибо за ответ)

Comment: Чтение строки из буфера будет после нажатия Enter.

Comment: Если вы хотите по символьно, то надо перехватывать нажатие клавиш

Comment: А смысл? Легче читать пока есть буфер, а потом парсить.

Answer (score 2):

1. Для ввода одной строки используйте *gets()*
2. Строку разбиваете на слова с помощью *strtok()*

Соответственно, в программе два вложенных цикла:

```
Внешний (по строкам), пока не EOF
    Внутренний (по словам в строке) пока не NULL
```

Каждое новое слово можно сделать элементом связного списка и добавлять его в конец такого списка. А можно сделать проще - выделить сразу достаточно большой массив указателей на слова и во внутреннем цикле наращивать индекс этого массива.